# Multiple popup windows - information is the same in all of them

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my modals. I'm creating my first portfolio website using js and the popup window is not working as I expect.

Everything works fine, only when I open the portfolio item and click "project details" each popup window has the same information about the item. Project name, category etc. do not change. What could be the problem? I will be grateful for your help.

and JavaScript, HTML and CSS:

```js
const filterContainer = document.querySelector(".portfolio-filter"),
  portfolioItemsContainer = document.querySelector(".portfolio-items"),
  portfolioItems = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-item"),
  popup = document.querySelector(".portfolio-popup"),
  prevBtn = popup.querySelector(".pp-prev"),
  nextBtn = popup.querySelector(".pp-next"),
  closeBtn = popup.querySelector(".pp-close"),
  projectDetailsContainer = popup.querySelector(".pp-details"),
  projectDetailsBtn = popup.querySelector(".pp-project-details-btn");
let itemIndex, slideIndex, screenshots;

/* filter portfolio items*/
filterContainer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("filter-item") &&
    !event.target.classList.contains("active")) {
    filterContainer.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("outer-shadow",
      "active");
    event.target.classList.add("active", "outer-shadow");
    const target = event.target.getAttribute("data-target");
    portfolioItems.forEach((item) => {
      if (target == item.getAttribute("data-category") || target === 'all') {
        item.classList.remove("hide");
        item.classList.add("show");
      } else {
        item.classList.remove("show");
        item.classList.add("hide");
      }
    })

  }


})

portfolioItemsContainer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.closest(".portfolio-item-inner")) {
    const portfolioItem = event.target.closest(".portfolio-item-inner").
    parentElement;
    itemIndex = Array.from(portfolioItem.parentElement.children).indexOf(
      portfolioItem);
    screenshots = portfolioItems[itemIndex].querySelector(".portfolio-item-img img").getAttribute("data-screenshots");

    screenshots = screenshots.split(",");
    if (screenshots.length === 1) {
      prevBtn.style.display = "none";
      nextBtn.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      prevBtn.style.display = "block";
      nextBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
    slideIndex = 0;
    popupToggle();
    popupSlideshow();
    popupDetails();
  }
})

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popupToggle();
  if (projectDetailsContainer.classList.contains("active")) {
    popupDetails();
  }
})

function popupToggle() {
  popup.classList.toggle("open");
  bodyScrollingToggle();

}

function popupSlideshow() {
  const imgSrc = screenshots[slideIndex];
  const popupImg = popup.querySelector(".pp-img");
  popupImg.src = imgSrc;

  popup.querySelector(".pp-counter").innerHTML = (slideIndex + 1) + " of " +
    screenshots.length;
}


nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (slideIndex === screenshots.length - 1) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  } else {
    slideIndex++;
  }
  popupSlideshow();

})


prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (slideIndex === 0) {
    slideIndex = screenshots.length - 1
  } else {
    slideIndex--;
  }
  popupSlideshow();

})

function popupDetails() {

  if (!portfolioItems[itemIndex].querySelector(".portfolio-item-details")) {
    projectDetailsBtn.style.display = "none";
    return;
  }
  projectDetailsBtn.style.display = "block";
  const details = portfolioItems[itemIndex].querySelector(".portfolio-item-details").innerHTML;
  popup.querySelector(".pp-project-details").innerHTML = details;
  const title = portfolioItems[itemIndex].querySelector(".portfolio-item-title").innerHTML;
  popup.querySelector(".pp-title h2").innerHTML = title;
  const category = portfolioItems[itemIndex].getAttribute("data-category");
  console.log(category);
  popup.querySelector(".pp-project-category").innerHTML = category.split("-").join("-");
}



projectDetailsBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popupDetails();
})



function popupDetails() {
  if (projectDetailsContainer.classList.contains("active")) {
    projectDetailsBtn.querySelector("i").classList.remove("fa-minus");
    projectDetailsBtn.querySelector("i").classList.add("fa-plus");
    projectDetailsContainer.classList.remove("active");
    projectDetailsContainer.style.maxHeight = 0 + "px"
  } else {
    projectDetailsBtn.querySelector("i").classList.remove("fa-plus");
    projectDetailsBtn.querySelector("i").classList.add("fa-minus");
    projectDetailsContainer.classList.add("active");
    projectDetailsContainer.style.maxHeight = projectDetailsContainer.
    scrollHeight + "px";
    popup.scrollTo(0, projectDetailsContainer.offsetTop);
  }


}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Clicker+Script&family=Montserrat&family=Oooh+Baby&family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
:root {
  --bg-black-900: #f2f2fc;
  --bg-black-100: #fdf9ff;
  --bg-black-50: #e8dfec;
  --text-black-900: #302e4d;
  --text-black-700: #504e70;
  --outer-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #d0d0d0, -3px -3px 3px #f8f8f8;
  --outer-shadow-0: 0 0 0 #d0d0d0, 0 0 0 #f8f8f8;
  --inner-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px #d0d0d0, inset -3px -3px 3px #f8f8f8;
  --bg-opacity: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.padd-10 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Poppins' sans-serif;
}

body.stop-scrolling {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.section {
  background: var(--bg-black-900);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.padd-15 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.containerr {
  max-width: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.section .containerr {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.section .container {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.section-title {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.section-title h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: var(--text-black-900);
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

.section-title h2::before {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: var(--skin-color);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.section-title h2::after {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: var(--skin-color);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  position: relative;
}


/* portfolio */

.portfolio .portfolio-filter {
  padding: 0 15px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.portfolio .section-title {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.portfolio .filter-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-black-700);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.portfolio .filter-item:hover:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.portfolio .filter-item.active {
  color: var(--skin-color);
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item-inner {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item-details {
  display: none;
}

.portfolio img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.portfolioo-item-img {
  position: relative;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item.hide {
  display: none;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item.show {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeInTop 0.5s ease;
}

.portfolio .view-project {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--skin-color);
  display: flex;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.portfolio-item-title {
  margin-top: -18px;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item-inner:hover img {
  transform: translateY(-23px);
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item-inner:hover .view-project {
  transform: translateY(-23px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item-inner p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--text-black-700);
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.btn1 {
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-black-900);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 15px;
  top: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn1:hover {
  color: var(--skin-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nacisk {}


/*portfolio popup*/

.portfolio-popup {
  background-color: var(--bg-black-900);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.portfolio-popup.open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-details {
  max-width: 1350px;
  width: calc(85% + 30px);
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-details.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-title {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-title h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: var(--text-black-900);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-title p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--text-black-700);
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(230, 228, 228);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-title p span {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-details-inner {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-project-details h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--text-black-700);
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.portfolio-popup .description p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--text-black-700);
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0;
}

.portfolio-popup .description {
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  max-width: 65%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.portfolio-popup .info {
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  max-width: 35%;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.portfolio-popup .info ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.portfolio-popup .info ul li span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.portfolio-popup .info ul li a {
  color: var(--skin-color);
}

.portfolio-popup .info ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-popup .separator {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(230, 228, 228);
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1350px;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-main-inner {
  padding: 70px 0 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-project-details-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-black-900);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 15px;
  top: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-project-details-btn:hover {
  color: var(--skin-color);
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-project-details-btn i {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 35px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  color: var(--text-black-900);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-close:hover {
  color: var(--skin-color);
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-counter {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--text-black-700);
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-prev,
.portfolio-popup .pp-next {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1010;
  color: var(--text-black-900);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-prev:hover,
.portfolio-popup .pp-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-prev i,
.portfolio-popup .pp-next i {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-prev i {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-prev {
  left: 15px;
}

.portfolio-popup .pp-next {
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bartek Lisowski</title>
  <!--css file-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="color-1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Main Container Start -->
  <div class="main-container">

    <!-- Portfolio Section Start-->
    <section class="portfolio section" id="portfolio">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="section-title padd-15">
            <h2>Portfolio</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="portfolio-heading padd-15 padd-10">
            <h2>My Last Projects : </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-filter padd-15 ">
            <span class="filter-item outer-shadow active" data-target="all">All</span>
            <span class="filter-item" data-target="web-application">web-application</span>
            <span class="filter-item" data-target="photoshop">photoshop</span>
            <span class="filter-item" data-target="mobile-app">mobile app</span>
            <span class="filter-item" data-target="e-commerce">e commerce</span>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!--- Portfolio item starts-->
        <div class="row portfolio-items">
          <!--portfolio item start-->
          <div class="portfolio-item" data-category="photoshop">
            <div class="portfolio-item-inner outer-shadow">
              <div class="portfolio-item-img">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="portfolio" data-screenshots="https://picsum.photos/200">
                <!-- project button-->
                <span class="view-project">view project</span>
              </div>
              <p class="portfolio-item-title">Web designs</p>
              <!-- portfolio item details start-->
              <div class="portfolio-item-details">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="description">
                    <h3>Project Brief:</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel consequatur rem libero similique quam ipsa facere porro voluptatum, hic in nulla natus nemo itaque? Cupiditate iusto cum sequi adipisci doloribus?

                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="info">
                    <h3>Project info</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Date - <span>2020</span></li>
                      <li>Client - <span>xyz</span></li>
                      <li>Tools - <span>html, css, js</span></li>
                      <li>Web - <span>www.domain.com</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- portfolio item details end-->

            </div>
          </div>
          <!--portfolio item end-->
          <!--portfolio item start-->
          <div class="portfolio-item" data-category="mobile-app">
            <div class="portfolio-item-inner outer-shadow">
              <div class="portfolio-item-img">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="portfolio" data-screenshots="https://picsum.photos/200">
                <!-- project button-->
                <span class="view-project">view project</span>
              </div>
              <p class="portfolio-item-title">Photosho Projects</p>
              <!-- portfolio item details start-->
              <div class="portfolio-item-details">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="description">
                    <h3>Project Brief:</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel consequatur rem libero similique quam ipsa facere porro voluptatum, hic in nulla natus nemo itaque? Cupiditate iusto cum sequi adipisci doloribus?

                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="info">
                    <h3>Project info</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Date - <span>2020</span></li>
                      <li>Client - <span>xyz</span></li>
                      <li>Tools - <span>html, css, js</span></li>
                      <li>Web - <span>www.domain.com</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- portfolio item details end-->

            </div>
          </div>
          <!--portfolio item end-->

        



          <!-- portfolio item button start-->

          <!-- portfolio item button end-->
        </div>

    </section>
    <!--portfolio popup start-->
    <div class="pp portfolio-popup">
      <div class="pp-details">
        <div class="pp-details-inner">
          <div class="pp-title">
            <h2>personal portfolio</h2>
            <p>Category - <span class="pp-project-category">Web Application</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="pp-project-details">
            <div class="row padd-15">
              <div class="description">
                <h3>Project Brief:</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel consequatur rem libero similique quam ipsa facere porro voluptatum, hic in nulla natus nemo itaque? Cupiditate iusto cum sequi adipisci doloribus?

                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                <h3>Project info</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li>Date - <span>2020</span></li>
                  <li>Client - <span>xyz</span></li>
                  <li>Tools - <span>html, css, js</span></li>
                  <li>Web - <span>www.domain.com</span></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="separator">

      </div>
      <div class="pp-main">
        <div class="pp-main-inner">
          <div class="pp-project-details-btn outer-shadow in-shadow">Project Detils <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
          <div class="pp-close outer-shadow in-shadow">&times;</div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="img" class="pp-img outer-shadow">
          <div class="pp-counter">1 of 6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pp-loader">
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <!-- pp navigation-->
        <div class="pp-prev"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></div>
        <div class="pp-next"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--portfolio popup end-->
    <!-- Portfolio Section End-->


    </div>
    <!-- Main Content End-->
  </div>

  <!-- Main Container End -->

  <!-- JS Files-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.12/typed.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need a separate modal per item; currently you're launching the same one each time. Please post your html and css here too in a fiddle (click the "<>" icon to open the jsfiddle code playground tool).

Comment: `portfolioItems[itemIndex]` is not the portfolioItem that was clicked.

Comment: Hello @NathanielFlick, thank you for making the post more readable. I've added HTML and CSS. Please let me know, what you think